# Sunspot Solr (or any other fulltext search engine) and filters to search with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, filter, full-text-search, sunspot

i know how to use fulltext search in rails 3.2 (i use sunspot solr) but i want to know if you can filter specific things. so you can shorten the list of search results.

i don't know how to do this so that's why i ask this question :)

Thanks.

Comment: Have you already read this? https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Yes i did but it's very hard to understand for a newbie like me.

Comment: any other people who know the answer?